# What would make a virtual call faster than regular one

Tags: performance, method-dispatch

I know virtual calls are generally longer than regular calls, mostly because you have to check the VTable before any virtual call.
However, lately I had a case (on a huge project) where removing the word "virtual" from a method actually slowed down the execution.
So I was wondering if you guys think at any case where using a virtual call would be faster than using a regular call.

Comment: Didn't you just give one in your very question (albeit without details)?

Comment: As I said it's a huge project (several millions of line) that I don't master at all. So I am not sure what would have slowed down the execution when removing this virtual call, and I am looking for an explanation :)

Comment: This can be a result of successful / unsucessful branch prediction combined with data and code cache hits / misses. (Plus a dozen other possible reasons.) Not really a C#-related question.

Comment: Did it perform better on every call, or was it unstable on its performance?

Comment: I tried several times and even profile the binaries with dottrace, and it's always better with the virtual call.